# How to reload a parallax page to the top section on browser back button In parallax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, parallax

I have implemented parallax in my website with animation and dynamic data in down section. But when I move to another page and come back to same page with browser back button i lost all my dynamic data and animation, I brought from DB.

I want to reload a page when user clicks back button so that user will be in top section.

Comment: @karidhmapednekar , people on here , prefer to see some code .

Comment: onload=function(){
var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'},1);
//if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
//else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
}

Comment: Here i do not reload page only directing to top section with above code which is giving me problem... I wanna reload page on back button click